# matrices - linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have tried this and got $a=-15$ and $a=-9$; is that right?

Consider the system of linear equations given by:

$$\begin{align}
−2x+5y+4z&=1\\
−4x+(12+a)y+10z&=1\\
(5+a)x−3y−8z&=1
\end{align}$$

(a) Determine all values of $a$ for which the system has a unique solution.
(b) Determine the value of $a$ for which the system is inconsistent.
(c) Determine the value of $a$ for which the system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: is that okay now ?

Comment: So your solution $a=-15$ is a solution for which question?!

Comment: Also, how did you come to the solution?

Comment: yes and when i sub those in for x,y,z i get 0=0 . why do i have to use the det?

Comment: a = 5/2 and a= -3 ??

Comment: @ellen Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let's consider the **Augmented Matrix** for the system

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      -2&   5&   4&  1\\
      -4&   12+a&  10&  1\\
      5+a&  -3& -8&  1
    \end{array}\right]$$

And then proceed by row operation to obtain the **Row Reduced Echelon Form**.

Answer (score 0):

@ellen Use Cramer's rule here

You can also solve it by Martin's rule via Matrix Method.

If you follow those steps in the methods I mentioned, you should get a correct answer for sure